# How to count incoming requests on IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I need to compute the rate of requests (requests/second) arriving to a IIS web server.
I am pretty sure that IIS maintains this information internally.
I have spent a reasonnable amount of time trying to find a way to configure IIS so that it write the rate down to its log file.
Guest what ? I was defeated.
So I have decided to get some help.

**Does someone know how to make IIS exhibit the arriving requests rate ?**

Comment: Couldn't the perfmon counters help with this which have some request/sec metrics? Or just parse the IIS log files and divide/count maybe?

Comment: Except performance counters there is no easy way to go deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Since there isn't an accepted answer, here is how to count this information natively using IIS:

Open ISS and on your home server, access the "Logging" option as showed below. By default, ISS will log every HTTP request that it receives, the hour and some data about the origin also.
[image: ISS Menu]

Answer (score -1):

Windows Performance counter has this info too.